# Pysftp - передать каталог

Tags: python

Использую pysftp, для соединения через протокол sftp

```
sftp.put('/var/www/test.test', './test.test')
```

Таким образом, берем test.test и заливаем файл не сервер под тем же именем.
Но что если необходимо передать не файл, а целиком каталог?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут есть 2 пути:

1. С помощью метода **pysftp.Connection.put_d()** и **pysftp.Connection.put_r()**

   Первый передаёт все файлы ,содержащиеся в локальной директории в каталог удаленной машины.

   Второй передаёт все файлы и директории ,содержащиеся в локальной.

   Подробнее можете почитать - [**ТУТ**](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html#pysftp-connection-put-d)
2. Сжимать каталог в архив и отправлять архив.
   Плюс этого способа в скорости передачи данных(зависит от степени сжатия),но увеличивается нагрузка на сервер из-за распаковки.